# FlatList Mobx ReactNative missing option for computed: get

Tags: react-native, mobx, react-native-flatlist, mobx-react

When I click the add item button, I see logs that an item was added but the view does not re-render.

My store:

```
import {observable, action, computed} from 'mobx';

export default class ObservableItemStore {
  @observable items = ["Item A", "Item B"];

  @computed get myItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  @action addItem(item)) {
    console.log("Adding to" + this.items);
    this.items.push(item);
  }
}
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { Observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import { Items } from '../../stores';
interface Props {}

@observer
class List extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Add Item"
          onPress={() => {
            Items.addItem("Foo");
          }}
        />
        <Observer>{() => {
          return <FlatList
            data={ Items.items }
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
          />
        }}
        </Observer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

export default List;
```

Why is the view not re-rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of array properties in the render (items.slice(), items.map(), items.length and etc).

https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html#incorrect-use-an-observable-but-without-accessing-any-of-its-properties